# how to get FromDate and ToDate if they have 10 continues days of absent?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Employee has 10 continues days of absence.

Below is the data what I have.

I need to get `FromDate(the Date Start Absent)` and `ToDate(the Date End Absent)`

The condition will be something  like this

```
if the 10 days Continuous where STATUS='A' Included STATUS='R'
```

FYI:

'A' as Absent

'R' as RestDay

'L' as Leave

```
    DECLARE @SomeTable TABLE ([EmpId] INT,[Date] DATETIME,[STATUS] char(1))

    --YOUR SAMPLE DATA
    INSERT INTO @SomeTable 
        ([EmpId],[Date],[STATUS])
    SELECT 999,'2016-07-11 00:00:00.000','A'
    UNION SELECT 999,'2016-07-10 00:00:00.000','A'
    UNION SELECT 999,'2016-07-09 00:00:00.000','R'
    UNION SELECT 999,'2016-07-08 00:00:00.000','R'
    UNION SELECT 999,'2016-07-07 00:00:00.000','A'
    UNION SELECT 999,'2016-07-06 00:00:00.000','A'
    UNION SELECT 999,'2016-07-05 00:00:00.000','A'
    UNION SELECT 999,'2016-07-04 00:00:00.000','A'
    UNION SELECT 999,'2016-07-03 00:00:00.000','A'
    UNION SELECT 999,'2016-07-02 00:00:00.000','R'
    UNION SELECT 999,'2016-07-01 00:00:00.000','R'
    UNION SELECT 999,'2016-06-30 00:00:00.000','A'
    UNION SELECT 999,'2016-06-29 00:00:00.000','A'
    UNION SELECT 999,'2016-06-28 00:00:00.000','A'
    UNION SELECT 999,'2016-06-27 00:00:00.000','L'
    UNION SELECT 999,'2016-06-26 00:00:00.000','A'
    UNION SELECT 999,'2016-06-25 00:00:00.000','R'

SELECT * FROM @SomeTable
```

And I would like to get the following output:

```
EmpId   FromDate    ToDate
999 2016-06-28 00:00:00.000 2016-07-11 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Which version of SQL-Server?

Comment: Does it need to be exactly 10 days? or just take the last Absent Days after Leave? For example if He Leave at 26th, then From date would be 27th and ToDate would still be the same at 7th with total 11 Days

Comment: the question title said `10 continues days of absent` or rather `10 continuous days of absent`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT EmpId, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN [Date] END) AS FromDate,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 10 THEN [Date] END) AS ToDate
FROM (
   SELECT EmpId, [Date], STATUS, grp,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmpId, STATUS, grp 
                             ORDER BY [Date]) AS rn
   FROM (
      SELECT EmpId, [Date], STATUS,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmpId ORDER BY [Date]) -
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmpId, STATUS 
                                ORDER BY [Date]) AS grp
      FROM @SomeTable
      WHERE STATUS <> 'R') AS t) AS s
GROUP BY EmpId, STATUS, grp
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 10
```

[**Demo here**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/511434)

**Edit:**

If the requirement is to get *any* number of consecutive `'A'` records provided that the population of the consecutive records slice is equal to or greater than `10`, the query can be considerably simplified to:

```
SELECT EmpId, 
       MIN([Date]) AS FromDate,
       MAX([Date]) AS ToDate
FROM (
   SELECT EmpId, [Date], STATUS,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmpId ORDER BY [Date]) -
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmpId, STATUS ORDER BY [Date]) AS grp
   FROM @SomeTable
   WHERE STATUS <> 'R') AS t
GROUP BY EmpId, STATUS, grp
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 10
```

Comment: I believe OP needs to get the total absent period (e.g. not RN=10 but the max RN). Which only really requires a slight modification to this, but difference in row numbers is the method I would also use.

Comment: @ZLK This is a bit unclear, but I've included a modified version of the query to address this case as well.

Comment: Indeed. But from the desired result (07-11, not 07-07) I was just guessing the OP wanted the total absent days.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I fully understand, but I think easiest was to count occurences of a `STATUS` which is **not** A or R.

The following query lists counts how many *non-A-or-R* rows are there 10 days back. All rows with a zero have a 10 days gap.

```
SELECT *
      ,tbl.[Date]-10 AS TenDaysBack   
      ,(SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM @SomeTable AS x 
        WHERE x.EmpId=tbl.EmpId 
          AND x.[Date]>=tbl.[Date]-10 
          AND x.[Date]<=tbl.[Date] 
          AND x.STATUS NOT IN('A','R')
       )
FROM @SomeTable AS tbl
ORDER BY tbl.[Date]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
; with cte as
(
    SELECT  r = row_number() over (partition by EmpId order by Date),
        EmpId, Date, stat = case when STATUS in ('A', 'R') then 1 else 0 end
    FROM    @SomeTable t
),
cte2 as
(
    select  *, g = r - dense_rank() over (partition by stat order by r)
    from    cte
)
select  EmpId, FrDate = min(Date), ToDate = max(Date), Cnt = count(*)
from    cte2
where   stat    = 1
group by EmpId, g
having  count(*) >= 10
```